# How do you create a Ribbon Button custom action that will appear on all kinds of lists

Tags: custom-actions

I want to create a ribbon button that will work with all kinds of lists. I mean, the same custom action should work against lists, document libraries, Announcement lists, etc..

Also. It should work regardless of the content types contained in the list.

What should be the custom action definition for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hook it to the 0x01 Content Type.

An example of the syntax used in our SharePoint Audit suite is as follows:

```
<!-- Add a new action to the SharePoint 2010 Ribbon bar for each list to show all audit entries for a list Item  -->
<CustomAction
  Id="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Action"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
  RegistrationType="ContentType"
  RegistrationId="0x01"
  >
  <CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.Documents.Share.Controls._children">
        <Button Id="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button"
                Command="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button.Command"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report16.gif"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report.gif"
                LabelText="$Resources:MuhimbiAuditProvisioningResources,ECB_ViewAuditLog;"
                Sequence="11"
                TemplateAlias="o1" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
      <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Share.Controls._children">
        <Button Id="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button"
                Command="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button.Command"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report16.gif"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report.gif"
                LabelText="$Resources:MuhimbiAuditProvisioningResources,ECB_ViewAuditLog;"
                Sequence="11"
                TemplateAlias="o1" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
      <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Events.Share.Controls._children">
        <Button Id="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button"
                Command="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button.Command"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report16.gif"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/Report.gif"
                LabelText="$Resources:MuhimbiAuditProvisioningResources,ECB_ViewAuditLog;"
                Sequence="11"
                TemplateAlias="o1" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
      <CommandUIHandler
        Command="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.Ribbon.ListItem.Share.ViewAuditLog.Button.Command"
        CommandAction="javascript:window.location='{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit.Site/AuditLogViewer.aspx?RequestFrom=listitem&amp;ItemId=' + SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id + '&amp;ListId={ListId}&amp;Source=' + escape(window.location)"
        EnabledScript="javascript:function singleEnable()
        {
          var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
          var ci = CountDictionary(items);
          return (ci == 1);
        }
        singleEnable();" />
    </CommandUIHandlers>
  </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a slightly different method. I only had to use one  definition for the button to be added to all the different list types now and in the future.

http://djeeg.blogspot.com/2011/01/ribbon-customaction-on-all-lists.html