# Show Ribbon Button on all types of Lists

Tags: list, list-view, ribbon, libraries

I want my custom ribbon button to show in all list views.  I found this example: [How do you create a Ribbon Button custom action that will appear on all kinds of lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/how-do-you-create-a-ribbon-button-custom-action-that-will-appear-on-all-kinds-of)

However, this also shows the ribbon button in Forms (Add new item, etc.).  I don't want it to appear there.  Only in lists (calendar, tasks, custom, etc.), libraries (images, documents, site pages, etc.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"` and  `RegistrationType="ContentType"` with ID set to 0x01 for custom button to appear on ListView pages of all the lists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
  Id="ShowHelloWorldButton"
  RegistrationType="ContentType"
  RegistrationId="0x01"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
  Rights="EditListItems">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls.ShowHelloWorldButton"
           Alt="Show HelloWorld Alert"
           Sequence="1"
           Image32by32="/_layouts/DemoSharePointRibbon/HelloWorld.jpg"
           Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
           LabelText="Hello World"
           TemplateAlias="o1"
           CommandType="General"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
         CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```